# How can I transfer jsp-config tag in web.xml to spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot

I am using tags in web.xml like the followings.

```
<jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/pages/comm/base.jspf</include-prelude>
            <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
            <default-content-type>text/html</default-content-type>
        </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

How can I transfer this to the spring boot?